# Cannot find (Excel Services Application & Visio Graphics Service ) inside the Service Application Menu

Tags: excel, installation, service-application, visio, service-applications

I have installed a new SharePoint server , and I wanted to create a new Visio graphics service and Excel service application, so that users can view excel & Visio documents inside their web browsers. but when I went to “Application Management >> Manage service applications>>New ”I cannot find these services as follow:-

[image]

So can anyone advice on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks Like you installed the SharePoint 2013 Standard versions, All the services apps you trying to create are part of Enterprise License. Check this link for [standard vs Enterprise Comparison](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-server-standard-enterprise/)

Now you should update your farm with Enterprise license key, You can change it from `central admin > Upgrade and Migration > Convert License Type>` enter the new key here.